# Appropriate way to load numbers from JSON file

Tags: java, json, serialization

I'm making a Java game, where I want to save files to be in JSON and I'm using JSON.simple library for that. The problem is, that when I want to read the save file, which contains integers, floats and other number types, I have to typecast a lot, for example:

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(scanResult);
player.setName((String) obj.get("name"));
player.setDungeonLevel(((Number) obj.get("dungeonLevel")).intValue());
Number x = (Number) obj.get("x");
Number y = (Number) obj.get("y");
player.setPosition(new Vector2(x.floatValue(), y.floatValue()));
player.setSpeed(((Number) obj.get("speed")).floatValue());
```

This makes code look very ugly and hard to read. After doing some research, I'm starting to think, that the library I'm using (JSON.simple) might be just too simple? :). I have found out, that JSONLib can save for example Float and afterwards, read it as a Float (that's basically what I want).
Another library which is recommended by a lot of people is Gson, but I'm not sure if it would work in my case, since in some cases I would just want to save an array of different map tiles (like doors, walls, floor which all have different properties) or items and etc., not an object.
I hesitate to use another library, since I would have to rewrite some existing code and JSONLib has some dependencies, which I don't really want in my program.
Is there any way for me to stick with JSON.simple without having to typecast all the time? Or would you suggest me to switch to another library and if yes, what would you recommend?
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Any reason it has to be Java?

Comment: You should try Gson. It's really great.

Comment: *would you suggest me to switch to another library (...) what would you recommend* I would suggest doing some tests with Gson and Jackson. I currently work with Jackson and works fine in both code readability and performance. Also, to avoid your problem about code refactoring, I tend to use [Bridge Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) to avoid having a direct usage of third party libraries on my code.

Comment: @djechlin Yes, I forgot to mention, that I'm writing the game in JAVA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Gson would definitely make the code more readable, here's how your above example will look:

```
class Player {
    private String name;
    private String dungeonLevel;
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float speed;
    // setters/getters go here
}

Player player = new Gson().fromJson(scanResult, Player.class);
Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(player.getX(), player.getY());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm really starting to think, that I should use Gson, but one thing is unclear: what if I want to save/load just an array of objects? Would that be simple as saving/loading Player as in your example or should I make some object which would hold that array and convert the whole object into json?

Comment: Gson serializes arrays into `List` objects transparently. If the array is the member of your root `Player` object, then you can simply add a field of type List to the Player object. If the List itself is a root element of the json, you can load it directly as shown above.